# How to deploy SSRS reports to my web server

Tags: reporting-services

I finished setting up my SSRS reports on my local machine by installing reporting services and configuraturing this to work with my local machine. My question is to deloy the reporting services to a web server so that I can run the reports from where my website is hosted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in Report Manager. Report Manager is a web site that can run on a separate web server or on the SQL Server hosting the SSRS databases.

SQL Server Reporting Services Basics: [Deploying Reports](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/reporting-services/sql-server-reporting-services-basics-deploying-reports/)

[Publishing Reports to a Report Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/reports/publishing-reports-to-a-report-server)